# Tensorflow of Jupyter Notebook gives "FutureWarning"

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I run a **Tensorflow** program in **Jupyter Notebook**, I get the output but also the following "**FUTUREWARNING**". I have created a Tensorflow Environment in Anaconda using: `conda create -n tf tensorflow`

I also initialized Tensorflow environment using command : `conda activate`

**PROGRAM :**

```
import tensorflow as tf
print ("TensorFlow version: " + tf.__version__)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework               
/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is    
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework  
/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is     
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework 
/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is     
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework 
/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is    
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework
/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is   
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework
/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is     
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

**TensorFlow version: 1.14.0**

```
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub 
/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is   
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub 
/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is 
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub
/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is 
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub
/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is 
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub
/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is 
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
_np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/atishrathour/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub
/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is  
deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the question? A [`FutureWarning`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FutureWarning) is not an error. It warns users that a function will be deprecated in the future.

The warnings you are seeing have been reported on GitHub in [tensorflow/tensorflow#30427](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30427). They are likely benign, but if you want to get rid of them, a potential solution is to create or a new conda environment and reinstall tensorflow with conda or pip.

So either:

```
conda create --name tf-env tensorflow
```

or

```
conda create --name tf-env python=3.6
conda activate tf-env
pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow
```

Comment: Didn't work. Jupyter Notebook shows "Module not Found Error".